# shuffle one column based upon factors in another R

Tags: r

I created a dataframe to illustrate my problem.  I am relatively new to R.

```
    #### permutation problem

a <- c("beagle", "beagle", "beagle", "basset", "basset")
b <- c(44, 33, 22, 34, 42)
c <- c(1:5)
d <- c(7:11)

dogframe <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))


output
> dogframe
       a  b c  d
1 beagle 44 1  7
2 beagle 33 2  8
3 beagle 22 3  9
4 basset 34 4 10
5 basset 42 5 11
>
```

What I want to do is randomly shuffle column b by the factors in column a.  So the values 44,33 and 22 will be shuffled for "beagle" and 34 and 42 will be shuffled for basset. I want the result to be a dataframe resembling the original with only shuffled values in column b.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
dogframe$b <- ave(dogframe$b, dogframe$a, FUN = sample)
```

which you can also write:

```
dogframe$b <- with(dogframe, ave(b, a, FUN = sample))
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, you have `base` and `plyr` solutions already. Here's the third alternative in questions like this:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dogframe)

DT[,b:=sample(b),by=a]
```

This overwrites the `b` column; if you wanted it in a separate copy, you'd do:

```
DT2 <- copy(DT)[,b:=sample(b),by=a]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with the `plyr` package, this way :

```
ddply(dogframe, "a", function(df) { df$b <- df$b[sample(nrow(df))]; df})
```

Which gives, for example :

```
       a  b c  d
1 basset 42 4 10
2 basset 34 5 11
3 beagle 44 1  7
4 beagle 22 2  8
5 beagle 33 3  9
```